# What does y'all mean?

Tags: word-meaning, idiomatic-language, slang

From ["Been Throwin Money"](https://youtu.be/j7epJg9Hzqs?t=60) by 2 Pistols:

> You see I'm ballin' on a different level
> Flintstones in my watch y'all rock pebbles

I am not sure I understand this lyrics.

> You see I am rocking expensive stuffs on a different level. Flintstones are inside my watch. You are all rocking pebbled instead of expensive Flintstones.

Is that what those lyrics mean? How come there are so many words omitted?

Comment: It's anybody's guess. It's rap. A lot of times, there's no making sense of it. The only reason I'm commenting is to let you know that Pebbles is the name of Fred and Wilma Flintstone's daughter, who in the episodes where she's a young adult is pretty hot, so it could have some kind of sexual connotation or be thrown in to make you invent your own meaning or interpretation, which lyracists are also wont to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. First of all:

> How come there are so many words omitted?

This is a song and the rules of grammar can be stretched *very* far in poetry and song lyrics. In rap music the rules are often stretched even farther.

---

> Flintstones in my watch, y'all rock pebbles

The rapper is singing about his wristwatch, which has jewelry in it:

[image: A heavily bejeweled watch]
<sup>Source: [Smalody Store](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32819461145.html) on AliExpress</sup>

"Stone" here means a gemstone, usually a diamond specifically ([definition 3 at wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stone#English)).

"Flintstones" is a reference to the cartoon *[The Flintstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones)*, in which the main character worked at a quarry. The rapper says his watch has *flintstones* which are implied to be larger and more expensive than the smaller *pebbles* on the watches of the people he is speaking to. "A flintstone" does not have any specific meaning regarding gems (though [flint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint) is a type of rock), but it does provide a second layer of meaning: "pebbles" can be a reference to [Pebbles cereal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebbles_cereal), which are advertised using characters from *The Flintstones*, or to the Flintstones' daughter Pebbles as Benjamin Harman points out. Both Pebbles cereal and Pebbles the baby are small things.

[image: A box of Cocoa Pebbles]
<sup>Source: [Post Brands](https://www.postpebblescereal.com/products/cocoa-pebbles/)</sup>

"[Rock](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rock#English)" ties everything together: as a verb (etymology 2, definition 5) it means to *wear* or *sport* a thing (in this case, the wristwatch sports large jewels)—but as a noun (etymology 1, definition 1.5) it is slang for, again, a gemstone, specifically a large diamond. "Y'all" is a colloquialism; it is abbreviated form of "you all." If "rock" is a verb, the line can be read as meaning:

> You all have [watches that have] small pebbles for gems.

But because of the poetic license afforded song lyrics, and because the rapper uses [African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), it is also possible that "rock" is used as a noun, and the line can be read:

> All of your rocks are pebbles [not really "rocks" at all].

---

So the line means:

> My watch has large and expensive gemstones, while your watches only have small ones.